# Techniques to find out web frameworks a site uses

Tags: website

How can I find out which web frameworks/java-script libraries a site uses, specially their versions from a web-browser like Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: Not an answer, but there is no way to be 100% sure about the web framework they are using without having access to their servers. The best you can do is make guesses based on the structure of the website, or comments in code, etc. As for JavaScript libraries, you can just click View Source in your browser. :)

Comment: This is off-topic: http://superuser.com/faq Might be better suited for WebCheatSheet or something like that.

Comment: this may be appropriate to [Doctype](http://doctype.com/), but i'm not very knowledgeable about that site.  check their FAQ before posting.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty good and does most/all of the work for you.

> [Detect CMS, framework and technologies being used by a website](http://guess.scritch.org/)

Also this question over at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) gives quite a few tips.

> [How do you determine what technology a website is built on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396739/how-do-you-determine-what-technology-a-website-is-built-on)